# Eclipse plugin install error

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to install the google plugin for eclipse but the installer keeps telling me :

> An error occurred during the
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust phase

I've tried firstly to install from internet but then canceled it because of the poor speed. Then I download it and tried to install locally, then I have this problem. I'm using Eclipse 3.7.1 and the google plugin is also for version 3.7.

I've tried also to clean up the configuration folder by deleting anythings has the name equinox but that's no use.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Here goes the error log:

```
!SESSION 2012-02-03 06:30:06.977 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20110909-1335
java.version=1.6.0_22
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine 4 4 2012-02-03 06:33:17.752
!MESSAGE An error occurred during the org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust phase.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine 4 0 2012-02-03 06:33:17.752
!MESSAGE session context was:(profile=epp.package.java, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust, operand=, action=).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine 4 0 2012-02-03 06:33:17.752
!MESSAGE Error reading signed content.
!STACK 0
java.io.IOException: The file "/home/darkjh/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.core_2.5.1.v201201120043-rel-r37.jar" does not exist
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.bundlefile.ZipBundleFile.<init>(ZipBundleFile.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.bundlefile.ZipBundleFile.<init>(ZipBundleFile.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.signedcontent.SignedBundleHook.getSignedContent(SignedBundleHook.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CertificateChecker.checkCertificates(CertificateChecker.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CertificateChecker.start(CertificateChecker.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust.completePhase(CheckTrust.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Phase.postPerform(Phase.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Phase.perform(Phase.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.PhaseSet.perform(PhaseSet.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations.ProvisioningSession.performProvisioningPlan(ProvisioningSession.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations.ProfileModificationJob.runModal(ProfileModificationJob.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations.ProvisioningJob.run(ProvisioningJob.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

Comment: You can try with a fresh instalation of eclipse, and installing the plugind with the update URL (from internet), if your connection is poor, just wait a little more :)

Comment: yes that's what I will try at last

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I think it's a failure inside Eclipse. Now I've downloaded a clean one and the installation was all ok.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're missing a file with the given name. (com.google.appengine.eclipse.core_2.5.1.v201201120043-rel-r37.jar) Try searching for it using your favorite search engine and placing it manually in the specified location. (/home/darkjh/eclipse/plugins/)

Comment: I've download the site files for local installation. And I set it to install plugin locally, the missing file is just there, and the installer should copy it to the plugin folder. I've just copied the missing file into plugin folder, and the error continue to claim another missing file. Is that normal? I should copy all the installation files into eclipse/plugin?

Comment: I believe you should copy all those files, yes.

Comment: Ok I did it, I've copied all the files that I can find in GPE repo into the corresponding folder in eclipse. But it keeps giving error, for example I've a abc.jar file in the plugin folder, it now claims for a abc file, without the .jar postfix. And what is that? I don't think it is a normal behaviour for a installer.